# Beautiful soup not returning expected result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was using beautifulsoup to try to collect information from a website "https://www.yugiohcardguide.com/archetype/abyss-actor.html". The card information is set up relatively neatly. Below is a picture of the html that I was trying to parse through.

[image]

I am trying to get all of the  tags that contain the information for a single card in each row.

below is the code that I used

```
def get_card_info_from_link(self, link):
    
    new_link=pre_url+'/'+link #link to the archtype page
    html=requests.get(new_link).content
    soup=bs(html,'lxml')
    info_rows=soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
    
    found_cards=[]
    
    # count=0
    
    
    for i in info_rows:
            
            print('='*50)
            print(i)
            print('='*50)
            
            # count+=1
```

Here is the link to the output that I am getting.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J09nhhrfdje-ktxEG3KLcGwK1cR93ZOo/view?usp=sharing

the first couple of outputs with the equal sign separators are exactly what I was looking for, but at one point it no longer outputs the previous format and instead is an item that contains multiple  tags instead of each tag being on its own.

I cannot wrap my head around what the problem is. maybe I am just overlooking a key detail that I am oblivious to.

Comment: Try to look at the content of `html`. Some of the actual content you see in the browser might be generated by JavaScript.

Comment: Besides, this is definitely not a [example]. External links don't wouldn't.

Comment: ^^ Agreed. This looks like a case where you could reduce this to an example we can reproduce and with a clearly shown case of failure and expected result. The snippet tool via [edit] can be used to show the relevant html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the html is broken or have unclosed tags

```
<tr class="row2" valign="top">
.....
</a> 
<!-- No </td></tr> -->
<tr class="row2" valign="top">
```

there are multiple ways to fix, after

```
html = requests.get(new_link).text # instead of .content
```

fix it using `Regex`

```
fixed_html = re.sub(r'</a>\s+<tr valign="top"', '</a></td></tr><tr valign="top"', html)
```

or using `lxml` or `html5lib`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib') # or lxml
fixed_html = soup.prettify()
```

or using `tidy`

```
fixed_html = tidy.parseString(html, show_body_only=True)
```

then parse fixed html

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(fixed_html,'lxml')
info_rows = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will helps you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.yugiohcardguide.com/archetype/abyss-actor.html')
html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
print(result)
driver.close()
```